# java: 2D-Array with more rows than columns giving back: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D-Array which has more rows than columns. In this array I am summing up all values from one column, row by row and giving back the result.

Until there everything works fine, but after the last for loop I am getting the

`Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6`

From other threads I only got the message that this means the number of rows and columns is uneven. In my case unfortunatly this needs to be an option.

See my code below:

```
double max = 0;
int machine = 0;

for(int c = 0; c < excelMatrix.length-1; c++){
    double sum = 0;

    for(int r = 0; excelMatrix.length-1; r++){
        sum += excelMatrix[r][c];
    }

    if(max < sum){
        max = sum;
        machine = c;
    }
}
```

The code works right until the end, but gives back the Exception after the last for-loop of r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you loop through 2D array you use the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

as 2D array is just array of arrays and each of them can have different size. Your condition

`for(int r = 0; excelMatrix.length-1; r++)`

looks strange. Does it compile?

You switch indexes `r` with `c` inside the loop!

```
sum += excelMatrix[c][r];
```

Proper code will be:

```
double max = 0;
int machine = 0;

for(int c = 0; c < excelMatrix.length; c++){
    double sum = 0;

    for(int r = 0; excelMatrix[c].length; r++){
        sum += excelMatrix[c][r];
    }

    if(max < sum){
        max = sum;
        machine = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it does, but I am not getting the result I should get while doing it by hand.

Comment: It does work, but it still gives me back only 0 all the time. Looks like the code is not adding the values of the array to the sum. Do you have any idea why this might be the case? In my original code I got the right answer with the exception at the end, now I am not getting the exception but not the right answer. Strange...

Comment: Well, you have logical error e.g. `if (max<sum)` instead of `if (max >sum)`

Answer (score -1):

The proper code would be:

```
    double max = 0;
    int machine = 0;
    int excelMatrix[][] =new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    //System.out.println(excelMatrix.length);
    //System.out.println(excelMatrix[0].length);
    for(int c = 0; c <= excelMatrix[0].length-1; c++){
        double sum = 0;

        for(int r = 0; r<=excelMatrix.length-1; r++){
            sum += excelMatrix[r][c];
        }

        if(max < sum){
            max = sum;
            machine = c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

Above code will calculate sum from all columns and store maximum value from all sum by column to `max` variable.